# Rendering a tree as a subset of a force layout with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to have a part of a large force directed graph to be rendered as a tree, so the nodes in the tree will have a fixed hierarchy while the other nodes connected will retain their force layout behaviour.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Probably not with a force layout, but I found [an article discussing how to create trees with d3.js](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/01/tree-diagrams-in-d3js_11.html) which looks promising.

Comment: you can edit the positions explicitly. So for example, you have a tree and all the nodes in the tree are set to fixed and you set each of their coordinates. And the nodes that are not in the tree adhere to the force physics